# I am getting request from api. How can I get the file_url from it?

Tags: python, python-requests, discord.py

The code:

```
 response = requests.get('https://safebooru.org/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&limit=1')
        print(response.content)
        await channel.send(response.content)
```

request:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LbOh.png)

Comment: do you mean `response.text`?

Comment: you probably meant `response.text` (as mentioned above) but if you didn't try using `iter_content()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

@commands.command()
async def sb(self, ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://safebooru.org/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&limit=1')
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
    file_urls = [t.get('file_url') for t in tree]
    ...
```